# Rails pass a variable from a form to a different page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form that I would like a user can enter a number into.  When they hit enter, this variable is passed to another view and used.  I'm curious how to do this, I'm not sure where to start...

```
<form>
  <%= f.input :amount %>
  <%= f.submit :submit %>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the submitted form values in the another view by using param hash itself. In your case `"params[:amount]`". You can also use @instance_variable to store `params[:amount]`. Like "`@instance_variable = params[:amount]`" and use it in view/another-view by accessing `@instance_variable.`

Answer (score 0):

Submit the form to another view.

fields will be available in `params[]`.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define action for your form, like this:

```
<form action="url_to_controler_of_another_view">
```

then when users enter to submit, it will post into other controller for the url: url_to_controler_of_another_view , and then using other view.

But this is not recommended way of practicing MVC